# Telethon: не запоминается логин

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Хочу написать свой клиент для мессенджера Telegram на Python. Для этого использую библиотеку [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon). Беру пример кода [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744149/telethon-how-to-get-information-about-yourself-correctly/77744168#77744168)(пример кода с главной страницы Telethon падает при запуске):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = my_id
api_hash = 'my_ha'


async def main():
    client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)
    await client.start()

    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Этот код выводит на консоль информацию обо мне.
При первом запуске Telethon просит ввести номер телефона. Потом на учетную запись привязанную к этому номеру телефона приходит код. Библиотека просит ввести этот код и я его ввожу. Потом приложение распечатывает информацию обо мне.

После завершения приложения у меня возникают следующие проблемы:

1. Telegram разлогинивается на всех устройствах и приходится логиниться заново.
2. При повторном запуске приложения оно автоматически не логинится и просит заново ввести номер телефона и код. Но код не приходит и приложение так и остаётся висеть на этапе ввода кода. Приходится прерывать его вручную. При этом файл Test2Session.session создаётся при первом запуске.
3. Если поменять первый аргумент в функции TelegramClient (имя сессии), то код приходит и приложение логинится, но проблемы из пунктов 1 и 2 повторяются снова.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делают не так и как правильно логиниться в Telegram с помощью Telethon?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, это защита телеграм от возможного несанкционированного проникновения в аккаунт. Не знаю почему у вас так происходит, но логика какая: вы входите через бота, телеграм по какой то причине принимает вашу активность подозрительной, и закрывает все сессии, соответственно старые сессии, которые созданы ботом, уже не работают. То есть смысла хранить их нет, можете просто удалять. А вот почему телеграм вас блокирует - это уже другой вопрос, у меня такое было при рассылках))

Comment: Была подобная проблема помог переход на `pyrogram`.